# What is the principle of Code Hash generation in ink?

Tags: ink, cargo-contract

I come from ChainIDE, and I have some confusion regarding the generation mechanism of code hash. I tried to compile Flipper and [PSP22](https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts/tree/4.0.0-beta.1) in different folders, but I obtained different code hashes.

1. cargo contract 3.0.1 + rustc 1.69 + cargo contract build [flipper & PSP22 (Openbrush 4.0.0 beta)] codehash is different.

rust-toolchain

```
"source": {
    "hash": "0x72342d8f061221f13b1dfbaca24fabd929824c3cb9676f7537d1fb93fd7b5039",
    "language": "ink! 4.3.0",
    "compiler": "rustc 1.69.0",
    "build_info": {
      "build_mode": "Debug",
      "cargo_contract_version": "3.0.1",
      "rust_toolchain": "stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
      "wasm_opt_settings": {
        "keep_debug_symbols": false,
        "optimization_passes": "Z"
      }
    }
```

2. cargo contract 4.0.0 + rustc 1.71 + cargo contract build —verifiable [flipper] codehash is same but [Openbrush 4.0.0 beta-1)] is different.

rust-toolchain

```
{
  "source": {
    "hash": "0x68c1390a1e178c35ea4bd04e42d12f9d4b30113c3615fd469382302c71840933",
    "language": "ink! 4.3.0",
    "compiler": "rustc 1.69.0",
    "build_info": {
      "build_mode": "Debug",
      "cargo_contract_version": "3.0.1",
      "rust_toolchain": "stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
      "wasm_opt_settings": {
        "keep_debug_symbols": false,
        "optimization_passes": "Z"
      }
    }
```

I think the codehash generation might be related to the file path if the openbrush package is introduced, which is similar to eth. Is that correct? And I want to know the generation mechanism of code hash.